# All links in codeigniter are maintaining old segments - why?

Tags: php, codeigniter, linker

If you link off the homepage it works. So `www.domain.com` goes to `www.domain.com/parent1/mypage.php` but then when I link to the next page it keeps the first segment/parent (right word?) so the link becomes `www.domain.com/parent1/parent2/anotherpage.php` and so on.

After three clicks we have `www.domain.com/parent1/parent2/parent3/third.php.` Any idea where I did something wrong. This is also affecting images and all images are appearing as if they are in the category `www.domain.com/parent1/images/image.jpg` - not sure what the parent1 is there.

I hope that made sense. I am really in trouble here. Any help?

Comment: We have **no idea** what your code looks like... so any answer would be pure speculation....

Comment: Which code do you want to see? Here are parts of the config file:  
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.domain.org/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
$config['url_suffix'] = '';
$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';
$config['modules_locations'] = array(
 APPPATH.'modules/' => '../modules/',
 ADDONPATH.'modules/' => '../../../addons/modules/'
);

Comment: That does not help... Add some context to your **question**

Comment: All the answers below are good, but make sure you also check your routes, the problem may be there too (i doubt it, but if nothing else works you might have messed up routes.php)

Comment: I thought it was  my routes as well but that is pretty simple and seems right. $route['default_controller'] = 'pages';

Answer (score 1):

You either want to use base_url as Robert has suggested like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>blog/post/123">Post 123</a>
```

or you can use [site_url()](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html) like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url("blog/post/123");?>">Post 123</a>
```

or if you can use the [anchor()](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html) tag like this:

```
<?php echo anchor("blog/post/123", "Post 123"); ?>
```

Comment: My site was taken down and I am putting it back live without my programmer on a new host (I wish I didnt have to) so excuse me if my questions are too novice - where am I looking to change this code? It isnt in the config or index files... I am using pyrocms if that helps.

Comment: It will probably be in the /application/views/ folder. If you have no idea how codeigniter works, you'll have a helluva time with this.

Comment: Your telling me, I am a fast learner and have caught a lot so far. But I dont have the folder you mention above.

Comment: All Codeigniter projects have that folder. PyroCMS might be a little different.

Answer (score 0):

You're (probably) using relative URI's instead of absolute, that's what is messing it up.

When creating links, it's recommended to use [base_url](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html) function like this:

```
echo base_url("blog/post/123");
```

if you're using it inside a HTML template, just add PHP tags:

```
<?php echo base_url("blog/post/123"); ?>
```

You can also use it like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>blog/post/123">Post 123</a>
```